# Tricky qualtrics timing and autoadvance

Tags: javascript, timing, qualtrics

I am trying to set up some per participant specific timing questions on qualtrics. I have a practice block that contains 6 questions. I need to have qualtrics calculate the time it takes the participant to answer each of the 6 question, then average that time. In my next 6 blocks, I need the participant to answer each question within that average time plus 2.5 standard deviations. If they take longer than the average plus 2.5 standard deviations, I need the question to auto-advance to the next question. I know I will need to use javascript for this, however, I am not very good at coding. If anyone knows a way to help, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Why not start coding? Please review [writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question) 
to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.